# Limit flexbox height to browser window (currently it's overflowing causing vertical scroll)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have an app that fit the window size of the browser.

The menu should have a height that fit 100% of the parent and not have a height of 100% of the screen. I have this:

```
|---------------------------------|
| Header                          |
|---------------------------------|
||-------------------------------||
|| flex                          ||
|||--------------|               ||
||| Menu         |               ||
|||              |               ||
||| 1 item       |               ||
|||              |               ||
|||              |               ||
|||              |               ||
|||              |---------------||
  |              |
  |--------------|
```

I want

```
|---------------------------------|
| Header                          |
|---------------------------------|
||-------------------------------||
|| flex                          ||
|||--------------|               ||
||| Menu         |               ||
|||              |               ||
||| 1 item       |               ||
|||              |               ||
|||              |               ||
|||              |               ||
|||              |               ||
|||--------------|---------------||
```

My code : https://jsfiddle.net/vLbzLtyf/

```
<div app-context>
     <header>
       <h1>Application</h1>
     </header>

<div class="layout-flex-container row">
<div class="element">
  <aside>
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>
                          <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                          <a href="#">John Doe</a>
                      </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
                          <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                          <a href="#">Paul Smith</a>
                      </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
                          <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                          <a href="#">Jean Dupont</a>
                      </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
                          <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                          <a href="#">Xavier Lin</a>
                      </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
</div>
```

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div[app-context] {
  height: 100%;
}


/* ************************************************************************** */

.layout-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.layout-flex-container.row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.layout-flex-container.row .element {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
}


/* ************************************************************************** */

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 128px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 64px;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: rgb(63, 81, 181);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

header > h1 {
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 40px 0 80px;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: .02em;
  font-weight: 400;
}


/* ************************************************************************** */

aside {
  height: 100%;
  width: 340px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #424242;
  z-index: 5;
}

aside > h2 {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: black;
  line-height: 64px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: .02em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

aside > nav {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding-top: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside > nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

aside > nav > ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .04em;
  line-height: 1;
  min-height: 48px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

How I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to adjust your `height: 100%` in two places. Currently, it's combining with additional `px` heights defined in your code, which is causing the overflow in the browser window.

Instead of this:

```
.layout-flex-container {
      height: 100%;
}

aside > nav {
      height: 100%;
}
```

Try this:

```
.layout-flex-container {
      height: calc(100% - 128px);  /* subtract the defined height of the header element */
}

aside > nav {
       height: calc(100% - 64px);  /* subtract the defined line-height of the h2 element */
}
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vLbzLtyf/1/)

Learn more about the CSS `calc` function at W3C:

> [**8.1. Mathematical Expressions:
>   `calc()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation)
>
> The `calc()` function allows mathematical expressions with addition
>   (+), subtraction (-), multiplication (*), and division (/) to be used
>   as component values. The `calc()` expression represents the result of
>   the mathematical calculation it contains, using standard operator
>   precedence rules. It can be used wherever `<length>`, `<frequency>`,
>   `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` values are allowed. ([Read more.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation))

Answer (score 2):

For main containers like these, it's best to use **100vh** and **100vw**.

Read here about the modern CSS units: http://tutorialzine.com/2015/05/simplify-your-stylesheets-with-the-magical-css-viewport-units/

Don't forget to use `inherit` as much as possible on children elements (when it works). This way you ensure a proper cascade of height elements.